# Which grease monkey script i can use to customize the webpage i open

Tags: greasemonkey

I have one web page where i need to hide some images , some tags e,g hide tag with some id
so that when i open that page , then those elemenst should always be hidden or removed

Is it possible using grease monkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible using grease monkey

Yes it is possible.

Comment: Heh no problem. It's exactly what Greasemonkey is designed for but without an adequate description there's no way we can create a custom script. If I asked you "where do you click on my web page to make stuff happen" you'd have no idea what I meant either.